# WFFM Send Email Message When no Field Data

Tags: wffm

I have set up a WFFM form and am using the Send Email Message save action. In the Email I have fields from the form (Selected by using the drop down list of fields in the editor). If the user does not fill in the field (its not a required field), the *[FieldName]* appears in the text of the email. I would of thought it should just be blank? Can I override this behavior without writing a custom save action?

WFFM Version: 8.1 rev. 160304 Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160304

**Update**

Here is the Html of the email from the email editor in the save action:

```html
<p>[<label id="{43439BEE-8420-425B-8568-EFA16E6CD862}">First Name</label>]&nbsp;[<label id="{59FC07BC-F52A-430C-A77C-9B9C7D33D91D}">Last Name</label>] has contacted Blahblahblah.com with a question regarding Order Status.</p>
<p>Contact Details:</p>
<p>First Name:&nbsp;[<label id="{43439BEE-8420-425B-8568-EFA16E6CD862}">First Name</label>]</p>
<p>Last Name:&nbsp;[<label id="{59FC07BC-F52A-430C-A77C-9B9C7D33D91D}">Last Name</label>]</p>
<p>Email:&nbsp;[<label id="{DA938496-CD20-446C-9799-7F974AEAEC32}">Email</label>]</p>
<p>Phone:&nbsp;[<label id="{9EB25349-9772-4D5C-9690-E9301A1A6915}">Phone</label>]</p>
<p>Best Time To Be Contacted:&nbsp;[<label id="{0291B856-8E75-4E1E-A6A9-FCC72103560B}">Best Time To Be Contacted</label>]</p>
<p>Request A Call Back:&nbsp;[<label id="{65BE7408-3645-44DD-803D-BD97B1518FCF}">Request a Call Back</label>]</p>
<p>Message:&nbsp;[<label id="{312DA275-AD4B-4EE2-88AB-CE8A3083090A}">Message</label>]</p>
<p>Attachment:&nbsp;[<label id="{4D31A48A-F714-417A-9987-3BC127AA6DE9}">Attachments</label>]</p>
<p>Product:&nbsp;[<label id="{6DC3B0CE-6C57-4180-9C43-D91A7345A28F}">Product</label>]</p>
 <p>Product Category:&nbsp;[<label id="{71C70DBB-1A49-40FE-8667-B15E8C63B9E9}">Product Category</label>]</p>
<p>Product Collection:&nbsp;[<label id="{97813AA2-E7F8-4EF3-BF9F-1585F48CF690}">Product Collection</label>]</p>
<p>Product Color/Finish:&nbsp;[<label id="{A81E3A28-7D34-4407-94BC-D1F58A3AA8FD}">Product Color/Finish</label>]</p>
<p>Blahblahblah Brands order or confirmation #:&nbsp;[<label id="{8DE1665E-0996-4D1D-A685-410FB1D16246}">Blahblahblah Brands order or confirmation #</label>]</p>
<p>Product's Model or SKU from Proof of Purchase:[<label id="{78B78963-CE8E-404A-8782-AD0D8DA26E8A}">Product's Model or SKU from Proof of Purchase</label>]</p>
<p>Installation Date:&nbsp;[<label id="{05868311-16B0-4E74-B95B-C7F898F6A64E}">Installation Date</label>]&nbsp;[<label id="{95CE2944-4369-4854-A346-5EE9653368D7}">Year</label>]</p>
<p>I registered my warranty online:</p>
<p>Yes: [<label id="{D2C19DCA-C362-4FC8-B7DF-C7E7A9D7FF8D}">Yes</label>]</p>
<p>No:&nbsp;[<label id="{842B6C17-A1C1-499D-85E5-33BC6F4594B8}">No</label>]</p>
<p>Thank You</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

And here is the email I get:

Ethan Schofer has contacted Blahblahbah.com with a question regarding Order Status.

Contact Details:

First Name: Ethan

Last Name: Schofer

Email: eschofer@blahblahblah.com

Phone: [Phone]

Best Time To Be Contacted: [Best Time To Be Contacted]

Request A Call Back: False

Message: [Message]

Attachment: [Attachments]

Product: Blah

Product Category: Bath Drains

Product Collection: Blah

Product Color/Finish: Blue

Blahblahblah Brands order or confirmation #: [Blahblahblah Brands order or confirmation #]

Product's Model or SKU from Proof of Purchase:[Product's Model or SKU from Proof of Purchase]

Installation Date: October 2016

I registered my warranty online:

Yes: False

No: False

Thank You

Comment: Hmm it should be blank, have you checked the formatting of the email in the HTML view on the Save Action, could be some erroneous markup?

Comment: Assume if you enter a value in the field then it is sent through correctly?

Comment: @jammykam yes, fields are returned correctly if you enter data.

Comment: If the `ID` in the label matches the field ID then this sounds like a bug, I would raise it with Sitecore Support.

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when that field has been removed since the save action email template was created.

Have you renamed/removed any fields since you created it?

I'd suggest opening up the save action, removing the [Phone] field, [Message] field etc and then adding them back to the email template using the dropdown of fields. Then saving and trying again.

WFFM binds the [my field] placeholders to the fields based on a hidden id so if these are changed then it can loose the reference to the field.

Comment: @Ethan Schofer please mark as the answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: No dice. Im leaning towards @jammykam's thoughts that its a bug.

Comment: I've also seen it break when adding/removing/moving text after inserting the fields.  My only option was to remove and re-add the fields after closing the editor and reopening. I would call it a bug with Sitecore's code, but @AdamSeabridge that is the work-around I used.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in WFFM. I tried creating a brand new form on a clean install but it was still sending those un-expanded tokens for me. I ended up implementing a custom pipeline processor for processMessage. Basically, just copied the existing code from Sitecore.Forms.Core.Pipelines.ProcessMessage and add the code to remove un-expanded tokens at the end. It works.

Here is my patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <pipelines>
       <processMessage>
         <processor type="Client.Sitecore.Custom.Forms.ProcessMessage, Client.Sitecore.Custom.Forms" method="ExpandTokens"     patch:instead="*[@method='ExpandTokens']">
                 <ItemRepository ref="/sitecore/wffm/itemRepository"/>
                 <FieldProvider ref="/sitecore/wffm/fieldProvider"/>
             </processor>
       </processMessage>
    </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

And here is the code:

```
public class ProcessMessage
{
    private readonly string srcReplacer;
    private readonly string shortHrefReplacer;
    private readonly string shortHrefMediaReplacer;
    private readonly string hrefReplacer;

    public IItemRepository ItemRepository { get; set; }

    public IFieldProvider FieldProvider { get; set; }

    public ProcessMessage()
        : this(DependenciesManager.WebUtil)
    {
    }

    public ProcessMessage(IWebUtil webUtil)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull((object)webUtil, "webUtil");
        this.srcReplacer = string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "src=\"", webUtil.GetServerUrl(), "/~" });
        this.shortHrefReplacer = string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "href=\"", webUtil.GetServerUrl(), "/" });
        this.shortHrefMediaReplacer = string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "href=\"", webUtil.GetServerUrl(), "/~/" });
        this.hrefReplacer = this.shortHrefReplacer + "~";
    }

    public void ExpandTokens(ProcessMessageArgs args)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull((object)this.ItemRepository, "ItemRepository");
        Assert.IsNotNull((object)this.FieldProvider, "FieldProvider");

        foreach (AdaptedControlResult field in args.Fields)
        {
            IFieldItem fieldItem = this.ItemRepository.CreateFieldItem(this.ItemRepository.GetItem(field.FieldID));
            var str1 = field.Value;
            var str2 = "";
            try
            {
                str2 = this.FieldProvider.GetAdaptedValue(field.FieldID, str1);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                str2 = str1;
            }


            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str2))
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("WFFM Field Error Field Name: " + field.FieldName + "; FieldID:" +     field.FieldID, this);
            }

            str2 = str2.Replace("src=\"/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/-", this.srcReplacer)
                        .Replace("href=\"/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/-", this.hrefReplacer)
                        .Replace("on\\w*=\".*?\"", string.Empty);

            if (args.MessageType == MessageType.Sms)
            {
                args.Mail.Replace("[{0}]".FormatWith((object)fieldItem.FieldDisplayName), str2);
                args.Mail.Replace("[{0}]".FormatWith((object)fieldItem.Name), str2);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Parameters) && args.IsBodyHtml)
                {
                    if (field.Parameters.StartsWith("multipleline"))
                        str2 = str2.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
                    if (field.Parameters.StartsWith("secure") && field.Parameters.Contains("<schidden>"))
                        str2 = Regex.Replace(str2, "\\d", "*");
                }
                string str3 = Regex.Replace(args.Mail.ToString(), "\\[<label id=\"" + (object)fieldItem.ID + "\">[^<]+?</label>]",     str2).Replace(fieldItem.ID.ToString(), str2);
                args.Mail.Clear().Append(str3);
            }
            args.From = args.From.Replace("[" + (object)fieldItem.ID + "]", str2);
            args.From = args.From.Replace(fieldItem.ID.ToString(), str2);
            args.To.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", fieldItem.ID.ToString(), "]" }), str2);
            args.To.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[1] { fieldItem.ID.ToString()}), str2);
            args.CC.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", fieldItem.ID.ToString(), "]" }), str2);
            args.CC.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[1] { fieldItem.ID.ToString()}), str2);
            args.Subject.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", fieldItem.ID.ToString(), "]" }), str2);
            args.From = args.From.Replace("[" + fieldItem.FieldDisplayName + "]", str2);
            args.To.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", fieldItem.FieldDisplayName, "]" }), str2);
            args.CC.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", fieldItem.FieldDisplayName, "]" }), str2);
            args.Subject.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", fieldItem.FieldDisplayName, "]"}), str2);
            args.From = args.From.Replace("[" + field.FieldName + "]", str2);
            args.To.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", field.FieldName, "]" }), str2);
            args.CC.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", field.FieldName, "]" }), str2);
            args.Subject.Replace(string.Join(string.Empty, new string[3] { "[", field.FieldName, "]" }), str2);

        }

        //remove unexpanded tokens
        var str4 = Regex.Replace(args.Mail.ToString(), "\\[<label id=\".*\">[^<]+?</label>]", "");
        args.Mail.Clear().Append(str4);
    }
}
```